# Stars and Bars - Theorem

Tags: permutations, combinations

I've been told that stars and bars are a good method to solve certain questions, but the thing is, I've never come across this theorem. can anyone explain what the stars and bars method is with an example? Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: The [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is actually quite good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of ways of choosing $m$ objects with replacement from $n$ objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139395/number-of-ways-of-choosing-m-objects-with-replacement-from-n-objects)